# Authenticating user sessions in Flask while using flask-socketio

Tags: python, authentication, flask, session, flask-socketio

I have a Flask application that uses `flask-socketio` for real time communication between the server and client. I need to know how I can authenticate user sessions in `flask-socketio`. I.e., not allowing anyone to connect to the socket without being logged in.

Currently, what I do to authenticate if the user is logged in or not is checking the session variable for the `loggedin` value, that is supposed to be available in the session of all requests from a logged in user.

**For example,**

```
from flask import Flask, session

@app.route("/view_patient")
def view_patient():
    if "loggedin" in session:
        # Do stuff you'd do with a logged in user...
    else:
        # Do stuff you'd do with a non-logged in user, like showing the login form.
```

Now my question is, how can I go by authenticating a client that connects to my socketio server the same way, i.e., by checking their session cookie if they are logged in or not. Because I don't really want anyone opening a connection to my server and grabbing data that only connections from logged in users should have access to.

I have heard of flask-session, and flask-login implementation that is also endorsed by the maker of flask-socketio over here: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-socketio-and-the-user-session

However, to me, flask-login and flask-session seem complicated to set up and I really don't want to replace my existing authentication with another one.

Now can someone guide me on how I can go about integrating user sessions with socketio so that only logged in users can open a websocket connection without using any third-party solution like flask-login and flask-session?
If needed, my socket usage is something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request
from staff.staff import staff
from patient.patient import patient
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, Namespace
import threading
import json
from datetime import datetime
from flask_session import Session

app.secret_key = "key"
app.config["app_name"] = "appname"
app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "host"
app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "user"
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = ""
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = "dbname"
mysql = MySQL(app)
app.config["mysql"] = mysql

class get_patients_namespace(Namespace):
    def on_connect(self):
        patients_data = []

        def get_patients_data():
            mydb = MySQLdb.connect(
                host=app.config["MYSQL_HOST"],
                user=app.config["MYSQL_USER"],
                passwd=app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"],
                db=app.config["MYSQL_DB"],
                charset="utf8",
            )

            cursor = mydb.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)  # type: ignore
            nonlocal patients_data
            today_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM patients WHERE visit_date = %s", (today_date,))
            patients = cursor.fetchall()
            if patients != patients_data:  # type: ignore
                patients_data = patients

                self.emit(
                    "data", json.dumps(patients_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
                )
            else:
                self.emit("data", "No new data")

            mydb.commit()
            cursor.close()
            mydb.close()

        k = ThreadJob(get_patients_data, event, 5)
        k.start()

    def on_disconnect(self):
        pass

socketio.on_namespace(get_patients_namespace('/get_patients'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the `connect` handler. Just return `False` if your user is not logged in.

```py
class get_patients_namespace(Namespace):
    def on_connect(self):
        if "loggedin" not in session:
            return False

        # your logged in user stuff here
```